# ORACLE fastest way to know if table contains rows

Tags: sql, oracle, fetch, rownum

```
select 1 from MY_TABLE where ID=42 fetch first 1 rows only;
select 1 from MY_TABLE where ID=42 and rownum=1;
select case when exists (select 1 from MY_TABLE where ID=42) then 1 else 0 end from dual;
select count(1) from MY_TABLE where ID=42;
```

Here is 4 methods to check whether the table contains any rows. The last one is quite slow, but first 3 has approximatively the same time. What is the best practice (academically correct)?
Any other methods?

Comment: If `id` is the primary key, then I am **very** surprised that the last one is slower then e.g. the first one.

Comment: I believe the last is making a function call COUNT(1) which is causing it be slow.

Comment: yes, id is a key. 
my experiments showed that 4th method is at least 5 times slower then others if an index is already hot (in memory).  But fast anyway. 
If the index is the cold it is difficult to compare that is why i am asking.

Comment: If indeed you want to check if the table has rows, I agree with using one of the first 2 choices. Nevertheless, I also find it strange, like @a_horse_with_no_name wrote, that the last one is "quite slow".

Comment: First "fetch first 1" method has this row in the plan "Filter Predicates  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NULL )<=1"  It looks very suspicious. 
"rownum=1" has no such step. 
 "when exists" plan is simplest, but as I see no one is tend to use it.

Comment: You can try another version with exists: select count(*) from dual where exists (select 1 from my_table where id = 42);

Comment: Goran Stefanović it looks great, thanks a lot.

Comment: SORRY guys, ID is not primary key, it is just a NONUNIQUE index.

Comment: Ok, that explains why fourth query is slower. As for which query to use - it is up to you. You may want to add count(*) in the first two queries if you are using the query in the DB stored procedure - this way you won't have to catch exception no_data_found.

Answer (score 1):

Unless throwing an exception is acceptable, in which case you will need to capture it, you will want to use a count with rownum = 1

```
select count(*) from my_table where id = 42 and rownum = 1;
```

In this case, the return value of 0 means there are no rows, 1 means there are 1 or more rows.

While this gives the same results as your select with case statement, it is much less complicated and easier to understand.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to tell that ID is a NONUNIQUE index. In your example 
count(*) should calculate all occurrences (and I don't need this). It should be  a bit slower compare with a solutions where select only first occurrence.  
If ID is not an index at all your example is much slower.

Comment: I tried your example with "rownum = 1" at the end and without it and didn't feel any difference in time. They both are 5 times slower than "select 1 from my_table where id = 42 and rownum = 1;"

Comment: The only problem with your solution is that it will throw an `ORA-01403: no data found exception` if there are no matches in the table, whereas my solution alway returns a 1 or a 0. This is not a problem if you are willing to catch the exception and handle it appropriately. I am curious as to how you determined that the count was 5 times slower. Was this the result of a SQL trace?

Comment: I liked a lot this approach: "select count(*) from dual where exists (select 1 from my_table where id = 42);"  from Goran Stefanović above. It is without ORA-01403 problem.  "5 times" - just a time of execution: 0,007 vs 0.001.
But sometime it can be more then 5 sec. It is our corporate database. I don't know what happening with database in that moment, but I need a time less that a second.